# -bash: PURGE: command not found

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

I want to delete binary log files

following are my binary log files

```
  binary2.000001

  binary2.000002
```

i want to delete binary2.000002

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'binary2.000002';
```

It shows me:

```
-bash: PURGE: command not found
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` only handles Unix shell commands, no MySQL's internal commands.

This `PURGE` command is a command to MySQL.  It needs to be issued in the "mysql" commandline tool.  Or some other way to MySQL commands -- such as phpmyadmin, MySQL Workbench, PDO, etc.